# Liferay's messages - extend duration

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

is it possible to extend time when Liferay's Sesssion Messages (and Session Errors) are displayed on the page ? Normally it lasts like 8 seconds and it's not enough for me.

I use Liferay 6.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What king of message are you speaking about?
If you (example) add your message in SessionMessages...

```
SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "request_processed", "this-is-my-custom-success-message")
```

...and show it usign taglib inside your JSP

```
<liferay-ui:success />
```

It should appear in a green-backgrounded div, with success icon (for SessionErrors it is analogous).

They should not disappear.

Please, let me know more about...

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. Let's say I show error message using SessionErrors(request, 'my-error-msg') and inside JSP there is <liferay-ui:error key="my-error-msg" message="my-error-msg"/>. It keeps disappearing after 7-8 seconds. Same goes with liferay-ui:success. It's interesting that they should not disappear - in my project it does, I guess I can set this beheaviour somewhere?

Comment: Yes, they shouln'd disappear... :) Just a (stupid) question: are you sure you haven't any custom client side code that hide (/delete/put down) those elements?

Comment: Liferay does not hide the output of the <liferay-ui:error ...> tag by itself. Look at the surrounding DOM for hints where your custom code might kick in. Also your theme might execute some javascript that is executed to hide this - but there's nothing in Liferay that I've ever seen that hides error messages after a while.

Comment: You were right - there was code to hide messages! This project is so big I just don't realize about lot's of things - it turned out to be one of those. Thanks